# How to adjust SwiftUI List row separator inset with a Label like Settings app?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

In SwiftUI, I haven't found an elegant method with SwiftUI `List` api to let `List` row separator be like settings app style, while the row including a `Image` and a `Text` (aka `Label`).

## What I want is:

[image: what-i-want]

## What I usually do:

````
```swift
// here is my common code
    NavigationView {
        List {
            NavigationLink {
                Text("Detail 1")
            } label: {
                Label {
                    Text("Row Title 1")
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                }
            }

            NavigationLink {
                Text("Detail 3")
            } label: {
                Label {
                    Text("Row Title 3")
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "wifi")
                }
            }

            NavigationLink {
                Text("Detail 2")
            } label: {
                Label {
                    Text("Row Title 2")
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        .navigationTitle("Demo")
    }
```
````

[image: what-i-can-do]

Comment: I think it cannot be possible with standard List and my you need to work on a custom view.

Comment: show us your demo code.

Comment: If you use Label it sometimes works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.